# Subclipse- single programmer usage

Tags: installation, subclipse

I just started using subclipse for my class projects after a re-writing half of a project due to going off on the wrong logical branch.  Since I'm using it on my home systems, I have a couple questions whose answers I haven't found in searching.

Say I have  local separate repositories on my computers.  First, can I use a file sync to keep them synced until I figure out what I need to do to access the university's network?  (aside- only information available is about accessing the network remotely is thru PUTTY and FTP, which are not valid URL strings)

Second, in the same local system, am I correct in that once I check out a project and apply commits regularly, I don't have to keep checking out the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [SlikSVN](http://sliksvn.com) for hosting the repository, since it is free for <100MB storage, which is perfect for my classwork.  Also, I don't have to bother with tunneling through the school's network.

Answer (score -1):

You can access SVN repositories via ssh, using urls of the form:

```
svn+ssh://me@myhost.com:/mypath/to/repo
```

From the sounds of things with you saying you have 'putty' access this should be very possible.

I would avoid the "separate local repositories" route as much as possible since keeping them in sync introduces problems that having one, definitive location for the whole repository avoids..

Comment: apparently not, I tried a few things in subclipse and got this for my trouble: `svn: Can't create tunnel: The system cannot find the file specified.` Also, I can understand your feelings about multiple repositories, I have the same headaches keeping my Adobe Lightroom catalogs synced

Comment: Depending on your platform you might need to install JavaHL libraries. See: http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/PluginFAQ#head-214e1cef790ceb311232ec766435d62c7958ccb7